# python script to copy or move files containing a matching text to a new folder

Tags: python, bash, shell

I am finding out those files within a folder that contain 'ORC' text and the the length of the line containing 'ORC' is greater than 10. Then I just want to copy those matching files to a destination folder, which I am stuck with. My script is as follows :

```
import re, os
import glob
import shutil

dst = '/home/debarshi/Desktop/DestFolder'


count = 0
list_of_files = glob.glob('./*.hl7')


for fileName in list_of_files:
  fin = open( fileName, "r" )
  for line in fin:
        if 'ORC' in line and len(line) > 10:

            shutil.copyfile(fileName, dst)
```

Please suggest a way to do this.

Comment: Please explain how/why you are stuck.

Comment: I am not able to copy the matching files to the folder

Comment: `len(line)` seems to be wrong, you don't want the length of the line, you want its line number, don't you? so you could add a counter that gets incremented every time a new line gets read, and then check to see if that counter > 10 when the ORC is matched.

Comment: I actually want to line length when ORC is matched and if the match is found then copy those files to the destination folder, where I am actually stuck.

Comment: in that last if statement, maybe add a print 'found file with 10+ lines' and see if it ever prints that out. That would tell you if you are at least finding these files, etc.. Also in that if statement, I would add a break in there so that when it finds a line longer than 10 it just copies the files and breaks the for loop. Don't need to keep looking through the file if you've already found what you're looking for and copied it.

Answer (score 1):

Your `copyfile` should be:

```
shutil.copyfile(fileName, os.path.join(dst, fileName))
```

By the way, I notice that the pattern in the `glob` is `hl7` (ach-ell-seven), should that be `h17`?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the line # to be greater than 10, you should restructure your for loop like so:

```
for fileName in list_of_files:
  fin = open( fileName, "r" )
  lineNum = 0
  for line in fin:
        lineNum += 1
        if 'ORC' in line and lineNum > 10:
            fin.close() #close the file before copying.
            shutil.copyfile(fileName, dst + '/' + fileName)
```

You were not appending the current fileName to the destination path. Also, you were checking if the # of characters in the line (len) was greater than 10. It should have been the line number.  Also, You never closed the file before attempting to copy it, which is not good.

See [here](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/shutil.html) for the usage of shutil.copyfile.  When in doubt, use the full path to the source file and destination file (Same applies for the pathname in glob().